# How to get separate arguments from single arguments string like ProcessStartInfo.Arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

Let's say I have a shell command line. A single line of text, exactly as you would type that in shell. Splitting command from arguments is trivial. It's always a space after the command, in every shell in the world. I know, the command theoretically can contain spaces, but let's assume it's a normal command for a while.

When I just pass the arguments as string to the `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` string - it will work. But this is not what I want.

I want the arguments to be separated.
Each one. When an argument is like @"C:\Program Files" - it should be a one argument.

Getting that manually is just tricky as (s)hell. Because it's done differently for different OSes and shells. However - .NET does it somehow internally and I need to get to it not to reinvent the wheel.

What I REALLY want to do is to build an argument list first like this:

```cs
new[] { "dir", @"'C:\Program Files'" }
```

And then like this:

```cs
new[] { "cmd", "/C", @"dir 'C:\Program Files'" }
```

So it goes both ways - I extract arguments from a string, then I build an arguments string from separate arguments. All according for the OS-specific rules. My code should work on both Linux and Windows.

The catch is, it has to work multi-platform, so instead of "cmd /C" it could be "bash -c" on Linux, you get the idea.

The main point is to make the .NET to do all the quoting / unqouting itself, and AFAIK it does it properly on both Windows and Linux.

I really did search the Google and Stack Overflow for this - it seems like there's nothing.

I tried to get `ArgumentList` from `ProcessStartInfo` after settings `Arguments` property. It doesn't work. Setting one property doesn't set the other one. You can actually set both and get the exception when trying to start the process.

I bet the problem is far from being trivial. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I've done more research based on digging in .NET sources and GitHub discussions. It looks really bad (or really good depending on a point of view). It seems like there's nothing like this. So I basically need one method to quote one argument for the target OS, and one method to parse a command line into unquoted parts. For parsing I'll go standard, using FSM (finite state machine algorithm), quoting is trivial, it's just adding OS / shell specific quote symbols.

Anyway, if it's somewhere in .NET just hiding and giggling, please let me know ;)

Comment: **tricky as (s)hell** - Sorry that I can't answer to you but damn this made me laugh hard

Comment: No help from .NET.  This is missing for the exact reason that it is impossible to do reliably for any OS.

Comment: ` For parsing I'll go standard,` in that case check the [Command Line API](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api) which *intends* to become the standard at least for .NET tools. There are a lot of other CLI parsing libraries too

Comment: It's not just differences between OSs, it's also conventions and preferences. Some people like verbs/commands, some don't. Using `-` for shortcuts and `--` for the full argument name is a convention, not a rule.

Comment: Well, I don't need full parsing. I'm doing remote shell, so anything I type on my local terminal should just get executed on remote machine. And I think I found the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like it was not there yet, so I made a little braindead simple hack for it:

Pre-requisite:

```cs
public class SpaceDelimitedStringParser {

    public char Quote { get; set; } = '"';

    public IEnumerable<string> Split(string input) {
        bool isQuoting = false;
        for (int i = 0, s = 0, n = input.Length; i < n; i++) {
            var c = input[i];
            var isWhiteSpace = c is ' ' or '\t';
            var isQuote = c == Quote;
            var isBreak = i == n - 1 || isWhiteSpace && !isQuoting;
            if (isBreak) {
                yield return input[s..i];
                s = i + 1;
                continue;
            }
            if (isWhiteSpace && !isQuoting) continue;
            if (isQuote) {
                if (!isQuoting) {
                    s = i + 1;
                    isQuoting = true;
                }
                else {
                    yield return input[s..i];
                    s = i + 1;
                    isQuoting = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public string Join(IEnumerable<string> items)
        => String.Join(' ', items.Select(i => i.Contains(' ') || i.Contains('\t') ? (Quote + i + Quote) : i));

}
```

It just splits and joins space delimited strings using a quoting character: double quoute. I tested that is treated similarily on Windows and Linux.

Then another nice helper class:

```cs
public class ShellStartInfo {

    public ShellStartInfo(string command, bool direct = false) {
        var (shell, exec) =
            OS.IsLinux ? ("bash", "-c") :
            OS.IsWindows ? ("cmd", "/C") :
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
        var arguments = new[] { exec, command };
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(shell, new SpaceDelimitedStringParser().Join(arguments));
        if (!direct) {
            StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator ProcessStartInfo(ShellStartInfo startInfo) => startInfo.StartInfo;

    private readonly ProcessStartInfo StartInfo;

}
```

And another little helper:

```cs
public static class OS {

    public static bool IsLinux => _IsLinux ?? (_IsLinux = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)).Value;

    public static bool IsWindows => _IsWindows ?? (_IsWindows = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)).Value;

    private static bool? _IsLinux;
    private static bool? _IsWindows;

}
```

And we can test it:

```cs
var command =
    OS.IsLinux ? @"cat 'File name with spaces.txt'" :
    OS.IsWindows ? @"type ""File name with spaces.txt""" :
    throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
var process = Process.Start(new ShellStartInfo(command));
if (process is null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
await process.WaitForExitAsync();
var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
if (output.Length > 0) Console.WriteLine($"OUTPUT:\n{output}\nEND.");
if (error.Length > 0) Console.WriteLine($"ERROR:\n{error}\nEND.");
```

Works on Windows, works on Linux. Done and done. The split function is unnecessary here. I thought it can be useful to pass arguments as array somewhere, but well.

Passing arguments through `ArgumentList` property of `ProcessStartInfo` class is a little broken. It just doesn't work as inteneded, especially when I pass the arguments as one shell execute argument. Why? IDK, works when passed like in the example.

BTW, my `ShellStartInfo` class also sets some other properties of internal `ProcessStartInfo` that makes it useful to read the command's output.

In my remote shell it just works, the local terminal behaves as the remote one. It's not full blown `Putty` clone, it's just a tiny tool to have a little piece of "ssh" to a client device that doesn't even have external IP, open SSH port or may even not accept TCP connections. In fact - the client is a small IoT device that runs Linux.